# Error in Choosing the Multiple value from Query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am very new to SSRS. I have a query related to filter. I have a single table and declared a Parameter. I want the Parameter pick the value from table and able to select the multiple values.

In Parameter Tab: 1. General I choose the "Allow Multiple Values"
                  2. Available Values: I choose the "Get Value from Query"

In Database Properties
1. Go to Filter & Chose Operator "IN" and Select the parameter

Please help me.

[Error mesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjIvQ.png)

Comment: This is for SSRS 2008 R2, but it is still applicable to day: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have based your parameter values on the same dataset that you are trying to filter with the selected parameter.  This is obviously impossible, as how can the query run to populate your parameter if the query depends on the value of the parameter to run?

Create a second dataset that just returns the `Value` and 'Label` you need for your data driven parameter and then use that as your parameter values.